# Adding a variable in CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd, server, remote-access

I wrote a small script which intends to copy a file from our Servers, copy it to a local machine and run it. It works for me, however I would like to add parameters in order to make it easy for others to use it as well.

```
@echo off

pushd \\NetworkPath & copy batfile.bat \\ComputerName\c$\Users\UserName\Desktop & popd & psexec -i -s -d \\ComputerName -u UserName -p UserNamePassword "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\batfile.bat"
```

As you can see it copies the file locally to the Desktop of the user and runs the file itself. Please tell Me how I can use variables for ComputerName,UserName and UserNamePassword in order to have a query each time asking me what are the values.

Comment: `pushd "\\servername\sharename" & copy batfile.bat "%UserProfile%\Desktop\" & popd & "%UserProfile%\Desktop\batfile.bat"` should do the same job for any local user.

Comment: `pushd "%UserProfile%\Desktop\" & copy "\\NetworkPath\batfile.bat" & popd & batfile.bat` should do the same job for any local user as `COPY` will accept UNC pathnames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `SET /p` command:

```
@echo off
SET /p pwd=password: 
SET /p usr=user name: 
SET /p compname=computer name: 

pushd \\NetworkPath & copy batfile.bat \\%compname%\c$\Users\%usr%\Desktop & popd & psexec -i -s -d \\%compname% -u %usr% -p %pwd% "C:\Users\%usr%\Desktop\batfile.bat"
```

Comment: But `ComputerName` and `UserName` environment variables are defined already and should not be changed.

Comment: OK, I didn't know he wants to use the current user. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I would like to change all variables since I am running it on remote computers with different usernames and different passwords

Comment: So my first answer was correct :) I'll undo the changes.

Comment: @MichaelS: as I read it, any user on any computer should be able to use this batch to copy a file from the server (to his own account, not to a different user), so your revised version would do it. I might be wrong, but you could present both possibilities.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. However, we've had both variations answered. In case all variables are subject to change my answer is correct otherwise IdoM should take JosefZ's comment as a solution.